# Java class loading differences on AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, jakarta-mail

I'm having trouble using the javax.mail package on AWS Lambda.

When trying to get the content of an email, the getContent() method returns a `MimeMultipart` object when run locally. When run mounted to the AWS lambda java8 docker image, it returns `IMAPInputStream`.

I've seen solutions to this that involve setting the class loader on the current thread like so: `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.class.getClassLoader());`

However, this did not work for me. The classloader when running locally differs from the classloader when running against the lambda java8 docker image.
Local: `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`
Docker: `java.net.URLClassLoader`

I tried explicitly loading the class using the system class loader `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` like this:

```
Class c = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("helpers.MailReader");
MailReader mail = (MailReader)c.newInstance();
```

This works fine when run locally, but again fails against the docker image with this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helpers.MailReader
```

So there is something different about the system class loader across the environments. 
I don't know that much about Java, and it seems like I'm just missing something simple and making this more complicated than it is. 
What could be the difference in environments that could produce this?

EDIT: Debug output from javax.activation.debug:

```
MailcapCommandMap: load HOME
new MailcapFile: file /home/sbx_user1051/.mailcap
MailcapCommandMap: load SYS
new MailcapFile: file /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-1.b16.32.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/mailcap
MailcapCommandMap: load JAR
MailcapCommandMap: getResources
MailcapCommandMap: URL file:/var/task/META-INF/mailcap
new MailcapFile: InputStream
parse: text/plain;;     x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain
  Type: text/plain
    Command: content-handler, Class: com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain
parse: text/html;;      x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html
  Type: text/html
    Command: content-handler, Class: com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html
parse: text/xml;;       x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml
  Type: text/xml
    Command: content-handler, Class: com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml
parse: multipart/*;;        x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed; x-java-fallback-entry=true
  Type: multipart/*
    Command: content-handler, Class: com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed
parse: message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822
  Type: message/rfc822
    Command: content-handler, Class: com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822
MailcapCommandMap: successfully loaded mailcap file from URL: file:/var/task/META-INF/mailcap
MailcapCommandMap: load DEF
new MailcapFile: InputStream
parse: image/gif;;      x-java-view=com.sun.activation.viewers.ImageViewer
  Type: image/gif
    Command: view, Class: com.sun.activation.viewers.ImageViewer
parse: image/jpeg;;     x-java-view=com.sun.activation.viewers.ImageViewer
  Type: image/jpeg
    Command: view, Class: com.sun.activation.viewers.ImageViewer
parse: text/*;;     x-java-view=com.sun.activation.viewers.TextViewer
  Type: text/*
    Command: view, Class: com.sun.activation.viewers.TextViewer
parse: text/*;;     x-java-edit=com.sun.activation.viewers.TextEditor
  Type: text/*
    Command: edit, Class: com.sun.activation.viewers.TextEditor
Merging commands for type text/*
MailcapCommandMap: successfully loaded mailcap file: /META-INF/mailcap.default
MailcapCommandMap: createDataContentHandler for multipart/alternative
  search DB #1
  search DB #2
  search fallback DB #1
    got content-handler
      class com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed
Can't load DCH com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed; Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/mail/handlers/multipart_mixed
  search fallback DB #2
```

No solutions I found online related to this have helped

Comment: JavaMail uses JAF (javax.activation) to find the Java class that handles a particular MIME type.  JAF is normally part of the JDK.  JAF uses class loaders to find the configuration file that contains the mapping.  The configuration file is part of the javax.mail.jar file.  Normally the thread's context class loader will be able to find this configuration file.  The first workaround you tried should help in the case where the context class loader isn't set properly.  But if the loader you set it to doesn't properly delegate to the loader that loads the javax.mail.jar file, that won't help.

Comment: (Sorry, running out of space in a comment to explain all of this.)  The above more or less explains how it works, but not why it's failing.  I would expect the URLClassLoader to load both your app and the javax.mail.jar file, and thus be able to find the META-INF/mailcap file in the javax.mail.jar file.  If you can set the System property `javax.activation.debug` to "true", that might provide more debugging output that would help us determine what's going wrong.

Comment: I had debugging on already. It doesn't provide any useful info unfortunately. I looked into the mailcap issue. I checked the default command map like this: `MailcapCommandMap newmc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();` The command map contained the same mailcaps on both environments. I checked the dataHandler on both environments and that's where I found a difference. Locally the dataHandler contains a data flavor with the mime type `multipart/mixed`. On the docker image, the dataHandler is null. I'm not sure what to make of this yet, or how to fix it.

Comment: I also tried getting all the commands on the command map for multipart/* via: `CommandInfo[] ci = newmc.getAllCommands("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");` Locally there are 2 CommandInfo's of type `com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed`. On Docker there is only one. Again, not even sure if this is relevant but I'm just trying to find differences.

Comment: If you're finding one, it seems like it should work.  Problems like this are almost always class loader problems.  I don't know how AWS Lambda uses class loaders to load application classes.

Comment: Solved the issue. Had to do with the way I was packaging. I am using the the maven shade plugin to minimize the jar to fit lambda's requirements. I had to add a filter to include everything I was not finding - `<filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>com.sun.mail:javax.mail</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>com/sun/mail/**</include>
            </includes>
          </filter>
        </filters>`

Comment: Uh, ya, if you exclude the files it needs, it won't find them!  Of course, the intent is that you just use the jar file as is.  You should add an answer to your own question so others can easily find the solution.